# return false not stopping the execution

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am invoking a modal dialog which resides in a different location (another controller), into the current page. This modal dialog has an `Apply` button which should take some data from the grid in the modal dialog and let itself be closed and then populate that data into some place in the current page. This modal dialog is written in such way that after the `Apply` button is clicked, it redirects to some controller's action method.

From my current page, however, I should take the data from grid and populate it into current page and close the modal dialog. No need for any redirects.

So, to do that I am adding a `return false` at the end of the `click` event of the `Apply` button:

```
$("body").on("click", "#Apply", function () {

    if(true)  // do something 
    else  // do something else 

    return false; // this is not being effective
});
```

The modal dialog has a `$.post` call to the controller method, which is inadvertently being called even after executing the `return false` in the current page. The following piece of code is found in the actual modal dialog's (which is actually a Partial View) definition:

```
$("body").on("click", "#Apply", function () {

    if(true)  //do something  
    else  // do something else 

    $.post("/ControllerName/ActionMethod", { _someData: someData}, function(data) {
    if (data == "True") { // this particular action method is returning a bool, hence they are checking it like this!
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "SomeOtherController")';
    }
});
```

I also tried `event.preventDefault()`, but that didn't work either. Actually `return false` just calls `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` as I just found.

How do I prevent being redirected in this situation?

Comment: where did you put the return false in the second snippet? Are these really two separate event handlers on the same element for the same event?

Comment: If this is part of a form, you'll want to handle the submit event as well.

Comment: you can't override the `window.location.href = ` from elsewhere in your code which sounds like what you are trying to do

Comment: @KevinB: I put `return false` as the final statement of the `.on` method

Comment: in the second snippet?

Comment: In the second snippet (actual modal dialog's definition), return false is not needed since, until now, whichever developer needed that popup most likely needed that redirect. I don't need that redirect at all.

Comment: if you don't need any of the code in second snippet can use `off` to remove the click handler to replace it with yours... but your code would have to run after the other one

Comment: @charlietfl: Could I just chain the `.off` method to my first snippet? Is that how it is done? I am asking this because I have never used the `off` method.

Comment: yes...just make sure your code runs after the other one